# ng-click not working from dynamically generated HTML

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs

**HTML**

```
<table data-ng-table="tableParams" class="table table-bordered table-hover " style="border-collapse:collapse" data-ng-init="host.editSave = false" >
    <tr id="newTransaction">
    </tr>
    <tr data-ng-repeat="host in hosts|filter:search:strict" >
       <td class="hostTableCols" data-ng-hide="host.editSave">{{host.hostCd}}</td>
       <td class="hostTableCols" data-ng-hide="host.editSave">{{host.hostName}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Jquery**

```
$('#newTransaction').append(
 '<td contenteditable><input type="text" class="editBox" value=""/></td>'+ 
 '<td contenteditable><input type="text" class="editBox" value=""/></td>'+
 '<td>'+
    '<span>'+
        '<button id="createHost" class="btn btn-mini btn-success" data-ng-click="create()"><b>Create</b></button>'+
    '</span>'+
 '</td>'
);
```

**Angular Script**

```
$scope.create = function() {
       alert("Hi");
    };
```

Here the function called in the controller part of the AngularJS is not getting trigger from the ng-click event. The Html is getting appended successfully, but the ng-click is not working. Tell me solutions to make it work

Comment: you need to compile the new dom elements for angularjs to work... are you doing this manipulation in a directive/controller where you have access to the scope

Comment: @ArunPJohny: Am calling that function from controller. But where should I place the Compile function?? In a directive??

Comment: I don't know about the exact scenario, but you can do something similar using `ng-include` and templates.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Not a perfect fix, still!!! - just to show how dynamic compilation can be done

```
app.controller('AppController', function ($scope, $compile) {

    var $el = $('<td contenteditable><input type="text" class="editBox" value=""/></td>' +
        '<td contenteditable><input type="text" class="editBox" value=""/></td>' +
        '<td>' +
        '<span>' +
        '<button id="createHost" class="btn btn-mini btn-success" data-ng-click="create()"><b>Create</b></button>' +
        '</span>' +
        '</td>').appendTo('#newTransaction');
    $compile($el)($scope);

    $scope.create = function(){
        console.log('clicked')
    }
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/udmcv/)

**Don't use controller for dom manipulation - it has to be done with the help of directives**

Comment: I tried this method already and didnt know about $compile... So tried it from jquery

Comment: @MaximShoustin: Y shouldn't we use DOM manipulation from controller?? Any reasons?

Comment: @KiranKumar   Usability, code clearness, maintenance. The controller should be concerned with business logic, not interface manipulation.

Comment: How to achieve the same if you are adding HTML via service where $scope is not available?

Comment: @trainoasis you can try to use the parent elements scope like `$('#newTransaction').scope()` ie `$compile($el)($('#newTransaction').scope());`

Answer (score 36):

To make `ng-click` to work we need to *compile* this source by using `$compile` service. Angular should know about new generated HTML and therefore this HTML should be included to digest cycle in order to trigger `ng-click` and other events.

See <kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/588/)</kbd>

Create "compilator":

```
.directive( 'compileData', function ( $compile ) {
  return {
    scope: true,
    link: function ( scope, element, attrs ) {

      var elmnt;

      attrs.$observe( 'template', function ( myTemplate ) {
        if ( angular.isDefined( myTemplate ) ) {
          // compile the provided template against the current scope
          elmnt = $compile( myTemplate )( scope );

            element.html(""); // dummy "clear"

          element.append( elmnt );
        }
      });
    }
  };
});
```

after,  create dummy `factory` that simulates your *append*:

```
.factory( 'tempService', function () {
  return function () { 
    return '<td contenteditable><input type="text" class="editBox" value=""/></td>'+ 
            '<td contenteditable><input type="text" class="editBox" value=""/></td>'+
             '<td>'+
                '<span>'+
         '<button id="createHost" class="btn btn-mini btn-success" data-ng-click="create()"><b>Create</b></button>'+
              '</span>'+
            '</td>';
  };
});
```

And finally call it like:

```
<div compile-data template="{{mainPage}}"></div>
```

in Controller:

```
$scope.newTransaction= tempService();
```

For your example should be something like:

```
<table data-ng-table="tableParams" class="table table-bordered table-hover " style="border-collapse:collapse" data-ng-init="host.editSave = false" >
    <tr compile-data template="{{newTransaction}}">
    </tr>
    <tr data-ng-repeat="host in hosts|filter:search:strict" >
       <td class="hostTableCols" data-ng-hide="host.editSave">{{host.hostCd}}</td>
       <td class="hostTableCols" data-ng-hide="host.editSave">{{host.hostName}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

BTW, for now you can use the same directive over your code and compile any dynamic HTML.

Comment: Should I implement appending the html from directive rather than doing it by jquery?

Comment: As I showed in my example use Service and add in controller `$scope.newTransaction= tempService();`

Comment: @KiranKumar added Fiddle to allow you to loop up how it works

Comment: Just share my case, I use **Handlebar** to load template for table since ng-repeat is slow when data become heavier. I apply @Maxim Shoustin solution with `$compile( handleCompiledContent )( scope );` before attach it to the DOM, then I insert it with jQuery. It work on-the-fly. But one thing to point out, the `this` in handlebar for `ng-click will` not work if it is rendered under an object or array loop. It refer to the object/array variable instead in handlebar.

Comment: What if I can' have predefined div with the given compile-data directive, because the service creates it? And also can't compile via $scope inside the service ... I would insert div with compile-data directive, but who would compile that first to recognize the directive ... same problem for me then?

Comment: @trainoasis its not good practice to compile DON inside Service. use directive for that

Comment: @MaximShoustin i understand that, but I'm using angular datatables and you have to define how to render certain cells - you provide HTML there, and that's inside a service of course. Where would I put a directive in this case?

Answer (score 25):

you can use `angular.element(this).scope()` without use of ng-click

and change

`'<button id="createHost" class="btn btn-mini btn-success" data-ng-click="create()"><b>Create</b></button>'`

To

`'<button id="createHost" class="btn btn-mini btn-success" onclick="angular.element(this).scope().create()"><b>Create</b></button>'` 
is good

Comment: can we do this without scope.. I've declared my Popup Template while creating popup in factory.

Comment: How to send parameters init ?

Comment: @Sana  angular.element(this).scope().init(1,'false'); so simple

Comment: I am using this but it says Video is not defined. Any idea                  return '<input type="radio" name ="VideoRadioButton" onclick="angular.element(this).scope().productChange('+data.ID+',"Video" )" />';

Comment: You cannot pass ng-repeat iterating item as a parameter to the function.

Comment: `angular.element(this).scope()` won't work when debug mode is false like on production environment. It will return _undefined_ https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/9515
`$compile($el)($scope)` can be used instead.

Answer (score 3):

I needed to have Cordova open the dynamic link in a new window, so my solution was to put the ng-click on the parent element and look at the event.target to see what was clicked on:

```
<p ng-bind-html="foo.barhtml" ng-click="generalClick($event)"></p>
```

then

```
.controller('FooCtrl', function ($scope) {
    var html = '<a href="http://www.google.com">google.com</a>';

    $scope.foo.barhtml = html.replace(/href/g, 'data-href');

    $scope.generalClick = function(event){
        // have Cordova open the link in a browser window
        window.open(event.target.attributes['data-href'].value, '_system');
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to add $compile service here, that will bind the angular directives like ng-click to your controller scope.Something like:

```
var divTemplate = '..your div template';
var temp = $compile(divTemplate)($scope);
```

Then append it to the HTML:

```
angular.element(document.getElementById('foo')).append(temp);
```

You can also bind the event to the div as following:

```
var div = angular.element("divID");
div.bind('click', $scope.addPhoto());
```

Comment: Won't work if you are adding the HTML inside the service for some reason.