# Angular ng-click not working on dynamically created html

Tags: jquery, angularjs, datatable

I am using jQuery datatable and wanted to attach an `ng-click` on an `<a>` tag. The datatable code which does the same is below:

```
columns : [{
                type : "html",
                data : 'abcd',
                sTitle : 'xyz',
                render : function(data) {
                    return "<a href='javascript:void(0)' ng-click='hello()'>Hi</a>";
                }
         }]
```

ng-click is not getting called, so I tried:

```
return $compile("<a href='javascript:void(0)' ng-click='hello()'>Hi</a>")($scope);
```

which is returning a jQuery object and not the string.

Also, what is the correct way for attaching directives for dynamically created HTML elements?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19267979/ng-click-not-working-from-dynamically-generated-html

Comment: @Outlooker For creating the directive i need to have an html tag. right?. Here the tag is created by datatable.

Comment: provide a fiddle mate.might make it lot easier