# ng-click not working in dynamically created content

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have this function in Angular where I add a new slide with a ng-click in it.

```
var addSlide = function($scope, slideIndex, $event) {
  slideIndex++;
  var slider = angular.element('.slick-slider');
  var currentSlide = slider.slick('slickCurrentSlide');
  slider.slick('slickAdd', '<div class="slide" ng-click="addPhoto(); $event.stopPropagation();"><input type="file" class="camera-trigger" accept="image/*"><img class="photo-img" src="" /></div>');
};
```

Unfortunately dynamically created ng-click events don't work ([ng-click not working from dynamically generated HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19267979/ng-click-not-working-from-dynamically-generated-html)), how can I fix this in my case, since it's a function inside a controller, instead of a directive?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

you need to add $compile service here, that will bind the angular directives like ng-click to your controller scope.Something like:

```
var divTemplate = '..your div template';
var temp = $compile(divTemplate)($scope);
```

Then append it to the HTML:

```
angular.element(document.getElementById('foo')).append(temp);
```

You can also bind the event to the div as following:

```
 var div = angular.element("divID");
 div.bind('click', $scope.addPhoto());
```

Comment: Thanks man. Binding wouldn't be that nice since it would require unique classes/ids. How would the $compile service work?

Comment: var divTemplate = '..your div template';
var temp = $compile(divTemplate)($scope);   Then append it to the HTML"
angular.element(document.getElementById('foo')).append(temp);

Comment: does it possible to add `$compile` inside Service and its showing error like 'SCRIPT5007: Object expected'

Comment: Could you please explain more?

Comment: what if I don;t want to append this code in my html, as i am using it in DataTable so I am not able to add it ti html.... What should I do now ?

Comment: Then you can bind the event to your targeted HTML element: var div = angular.element("divID");
 div.bind('click', $scope.addPhoto());

Comment: @Joyson I don't know why you mention me here, but if you've then It's my responsibility to revert. And yes it will work but, I think instead of using this we should use `ng-repeat` with array.