# ng-click not working in modal angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

This is the **main modal** code:

```
<div ng-controller="CorporatePackageDetailsOpen20">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 class="modal-title">Package Detail</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body" id="packagedetails">
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <a class="btn m-b-xs w-xs btn-info" ng-click="getFormForupdate()" style="width:125px !important;">Update Package</a>
        <button class="btn m-b-xs w-xs btn-danger" ng-click="cancel()">Close</button>
    </div>
    <div id="addpackageform"></div>
</div>
```

**Dynamically HTML** is going to **append** to **addpackageform** div which is in above code. In that, which is dynamically created HTML, i have one button,  here is the **HTML code** for that `button`:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-10">
         <button type="button" ng-click="assingSinglePackageToOperator()" class="btn btn-default btn-info">Add</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

In my `controller.js` file, i have code:

```
app.controller('CorporatePackageDetailsOpen20', function ($scope) {
    $scope.assingSinglePackageToOperator = function () {    
        var iPackageId = $('#iPackageId').val();
        var dStartDate = $('#dStartDate').val();
        var dEndDate = $('#dEndDate').val();
        var id = $scope.id;   
        console.log(iPackageId);
        console.log(dStartDate);
        console.log(dEndDate);
            return false;
        };
});
```

When i **click on** `Add` button, it is not going to console the data.

Comment: If you are dynamically appending HTML you will have to $compile it. Are you doing it?

Comment: compiling means, what you want to say?

Comment: @bhargavponnapalli can you please tell me more

Comment: and where i have to do that and how?

Comment: Possibly duplicate question. Refer this existing question [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30468856/ng-click-not-working-in-dynamically-created-content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30468856/ng-click-not-working-in-dynamically-created-content)

Comment: https://jellekralt.com/2015/08/13/dynamically-load-a-templateurl-in-an-angular-directive/  for more info

Comment: i am getting this error in console that `ReferenceError: $compile is not defined`

Comment: inject your dependancy in controller

Comment: i put the `$compile` like : var $el = $(data).appendTo('#packagedetails');
     $compile($el)($scope); and got the error

Comment: @bhargavponnapalli thanks

Comment: @HarshalDhumal thanks