# How to Implement $compile(..)($scope) service inside angular 1.5 component, where $scope injectable is removed?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-components, angularjs-1.5

I am currently using Angular 1.4, in the process to shift to angular 1.5, I am rewriting all the controllers into component style and removing $scope injectables inside the controller. In one of the situation, I used $compiler service to compile dynamically generated html inside a controller in order to bind ng-click attribute to the controller scope . I got this help from the following question.

[ng-click not working in dynamically created content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30468856/ng-click-not-working-in-dynamically-created-content?noredirect=1&lq=1)

now how can I implement the same scenario using Angular 1.5? (I have to get rid of $scope)

Comment: You probably don't need to do this.  You can probably remove the `compile` code altogether and render the content dynamically in the template.

Comment: Thanks for the response @DavidL. If I remove the compile code, the ng-click is not working, I mean the click function associated to it, is not getting called.

Comment: Any update? I have the same problem

Comment: unfortunately no :(

Comment: It would help to see the your component code or maybe even a plunker.