# ng-click attribute removed after fetch the dynamic html content through AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I searched in google. Got some related links from stackoverflow. I implemented that script in my code all that code not working fine. Basically I followed this link [ng-click not working in dynamically created content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30468856/ng-click-not-working-in-dynamically-created-content/30468981#30468981) That one is working fine without clicking my `Click Here` link. I mean automatic fired to `invite()` function. Pleas check below my code -

```
function test($scope){
   $scope.email_output = 'Email already exist. <strong><a href="" ng-click="invite();">Click Here</a></strong> to Invite';
   $scope.invite = function(){
       alert("Hello world");
   };
}


angular.module('myApp').controller('test', test);
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="test">
   <div ng-if="email_output" ng-bind-html="email_output"></div>
</div>
```

I got my dynamic HTML content. But I saw `ng-click` not present in my HTML content. See my output :

```
<div ng-bind-html="email_output" ng-if="email_output" class="ng-binding ng-scope">Email already exist. <strong><a href="">Click Here</a></strong> to Invite</div>
```

Please help me I am new in AngularJS. How to get my `ng-click` attribut in dynamic html content?

**Edit:-**

See here my change code -

```
var email_result_html = 'Email already exist. <strong><a href="" ng-click="invite();">Click Here</a></strong> to Invite';
var temp = $compile(email_result_html)($scope);
angular.element(document.getElementById('email_result')).append(temp);


<div ng-if="email_result" id="email_result" ng-bind-html="email_result"></div>
```

Error Output:

[image]

Comment: angular attributes should be compiled, use this - http://stackoverflow.com/a/30468981/5954939

Comment: @AranS I saw that answer. Tested. But I want my `invite()` function should work while click on `ng-click="invite()"` I have used this code `var div = angular.element("email_output");
 div.bind('click', $scope.invite());` this code working fine. But this is automatically fired without clicking `ng-click` anchor link.

Comment: this isn't the way to think about angular.  You really should do everything in your power to avoid storing HTML fragments in variables when using angular.  if you have **no other choice**, then the only way to handle this is to use `$compile`, like the link @AranS provided, but this is a slippery slope that should be avoided.