# ng-click is not working angular 1.2

Tags: angularjs, dynamic, html-table

My code is:

```
var tr = $event.currentTarget;      
var el = angular.element("<tr class='detailed-document'><td colspan='3' ng-click='alert();'>Hello</td></tr>");      
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("detailed-document");
while(elements.length > 0) {
    elements[0].parentNode.removeChild(elements[0]);    
}   
angular.element(tr).after(el);
```

Comment: do you know anything details about `ng-include`?

Comment: For What reason he look on to ng-include why? the OP asking about why ng-click not working?

Comment: use `$compile` to bind `$scope` with your DOM element.

Comment: this link helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19267979/ng-click-not-working-from-dynamically-generated-html

Comment: ng-click is compile and link during digest. You seem to try to do DOM manipulation directly. Try to learn about angularjs directive.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30468856/ng-click-not-working-in-dynamically-created-content

Answer (score 0):

you need to add $compile service here, that will bind the angular directives like ng-click to your controller scope.Something like:

```
var divTemplate = '..your div template';
var temp = $compile(divTemplate)($scope);
```

Then append it to the HTML:

```
angular.element(document.getElementById('foo')).append(temp);
```

Referred from : [ng-click not working in dynamically created content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30468856/ng-click-not-working-in-dynamically-created-content)