# Compile angular-ajax generated code

Tags: angularjs, ajax, compilation

In my angular web app, I'll let users enter dates, and then using ajax I'll generate the tours that are available. To do this I want to generate code through ajax that contains ng-click calls. I'm trying to compile it to later add it to the div `#tourAvailPlan`. I am adding $compile to the controller (`app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope, $http, $filter, $compile, ngDialog) {`...). Still, when I click buttons with ng-click (generated with ajax), nothing happens.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19267979/ng-click-not-working-from-dynamically-generated-html) creates a jQuery object from the html string, but I don't really know why. I did it here as well anyway.

What am I doing wrong?

**Angular**

```
$http({
method: 'post',
url: '/ajax/tours/loadGroupTours.php', //Load tours in given date range
data: {
dateArr: dateArr,
dateDep: dateDep,
tourId: tourId
}
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    //No errors

    $el = $(response.data);
    $compile($el)($scope);

    document.getElementById('tourAvailPlan').innerHTML = response.data;

}, function errorCallback(response) {
    //Errors
    alert('ERROR in http request!');
});
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to append the compiled element. Replace

```
document.getElementById('tourAvailPlan').innerHTML = response.data;
```

with

```
$('#tourAvailPlan').append($el)
```