# Nested view controller and ng-click - AngularJs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, node.js, pug

I have 8 `jade` view that only one of them is loaded at the time and is filled by `jquery` into a `div` which has a `controller`.

Now, I have 2 question about these:

1. Does it necessary to define again the `controller` on top of my partial view(same `controller` with main `controller`) ?
2. All of these views has same `ng-click`. but after loading they doesn't work. However they work by jquery click event. Should I do any extra thing with them?

I had same problem with `li` element before, but I resolve it by getting help from [ng-click not working from dynamically generated HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19267979/ng-click-not-working-from-dynamically-generated-html) by using compileData but I can't get result with button.

Code:

**Main jade:**

```
div(ng-controller="elementCtrl") 
  div#ddd(class="col-lg-7 col-md-5 col-sm-7")
```

**Partial view sample:**

```
div#spPartial()
  div.col-lg-12.col-md-12.col-sm-12 
    span.col-lg-2.col-md-5.col-sm-5 Name
    input#EnglishName(name="name" type="text" ng-model="elementModel.Name" value="#{Name}"  class="col-lg-5 col-md-7 col-sm-5")  
  button(type="button" compile-Data  name="btnSaveElement" ng-click="saveElement()") Save
```

**Main part of controller:**

```
//It loads the partial view - It works successfully
$http.post('/api/elements/getElementTypesPartial',
                        {
                            "ElementId": elementId,
                            "ProgramId": newVal,
                            "ElementTypeId": elementTypeId
                        })
                        .success(function (d2) {
                            $("#ddd").html(d2);
                        }
//It doesn't work at all
$scope.saveElement = function () {
    alert();
    alert($scope.elementId);
}
```

And one additional thing is that I put `$scope.saveElement` in root of controller scope. I don't have any idea about how angularJs manage $scope, So I see `$scope.elementId` in client code. Is it right or I should regenerate it(`$scope.saveElement`) every time that partial is loaded?

Sorry I couldn't find any reference which describes these...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should get rid of the jQuery loading and use an angular router which will load templates based on route configuration.

Since they are loaded by angular, it does all the compiling for you.
The router takes care of the ajax to get the templates automatically also.

Controllers also get defined in the routing config so you would be able to remove `ng-controller` from the templates

The change over shouldn't take long since setting up routing config is fairly easy to get it started

This would clear up the `ng-click` problems

Comment: I've recently start with angularJs, so I have some problem in concepts. For example in this topic I change the subview by clicking on a ui-sref. It works perfect, but all sub views has a button with same ng-click. So I should get type of subview in ng-click function in controller. I don't know how can I set it! May be I should set it in controller at ui-sref ng-click

Comment: Suggest start new question. I think you want something like `ui-sref="items({id: thisItem.id})"`  but not exactly sure what problem is

Comment: I make new one! Please notice it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35054995/best-way-to-bind-sub-view-element-model-related-with-ui-sref-model-angularjs