# Custom close button in Ionic popup

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, popup

I create a custom ionic popup for photo upload. My problem that I am not able to close that popup by using a corner close button. 
Please help me.

---

Which look like

### [image]

Here my code

```
    $scope.uploadPhoto = function () {
    var confirmPopup = $ionicPopup.show({

        title: 'Upload Photo' + '<i class="ion-ios-close-outline popuoclose " ng-click="closePopup()"></i>',

        scope: $scope,
        buttons: [
            {
                text: '<i class="ion-ios-camera-outline thirty-text" ></i>',
                type: 'button-positive',
                onTap: function () {
                    $scope.takePicture();
                }
   },
            {
                text: 'Gallery',
                type: 'button-positive',
                onTap: function () {
                    $scope.galleryPicture();
                }
   },
 ]
});
  $scope.closePopup = function () {
      confirmPopup.close();
  };
};
```

Comment: close() function not been called I suspect.

Comment: @Atula Thanks for reply. when i inspect code i found that <i class="ion-ios-close-outline popuoclose "></i> it remove ` ng-click="closePopup()` from code. i am bit of confuse why it happen.

Comment: I have searched a lot and found that this might not be possible with ionic.

Comment: @Atula thanks for your reply.

Comment: well in future If you find something kindly post it here.

Answer (score 4):

**Below code works for me:**

*Code for javascript function:*

```
$scope.showPopUp= function(msg) {
     var confirmPopup = $ionicPopup.confirm({
        title: 'Upload Photo',
        template: '<center>Select Image from?</center>',
        buttons: [{
            text: 'Gallery',
            type: 'button-positive',
            onTap: function (e) {
                console.log('Gallery ' + picNumber);
                $scope.addImage(picNumber, 'G');
            }
        }, {
            text: 'Camera',
            type: 'button-positive',
            onTap: function (e) {
                console.log('Camera ' + picNumber);
                $scope.addImage(picNumber, 'C');
            }
        }, {
            text: '<i class="icon ion-close-circled"></i>',
            type: 'popupStyle',
            onTap: function (e) {

            }
        }
        ]
    })

};
```

*Code for CSS:*

```
.popupStyle{text-align: right;position: absolute;top: 3px;right: 10px;z-index:1000;color: #029dff !important;padding: 0px !important;background-color: transparent !important; }
```

***Call this function where ever you want to show the dialog.***

Comment: This is fantastic!

Comment: @NicholasKriedberg Thank you sir :-) 
Also, an issue I observed in iPhone 5s IOS version 8 is that the close button initially isn't visible but the dialog closes as we press the top right corner of the dialog making the close button visible. Also, the button is visible as we hover over it by long pressing the button and then moving the finger away from the dialog without triggering the event. Seems like an issue with the styling. Working on it and will post an update as soon as I fix it.

Answer (score 3):

Make it simple...
In cancel button

```
buttons: [{ 
    text: '<i class="icon ion-close-circled"></i>',
    type:'popclose',
    onTap: function(e) {

    }
}],
```

And In Css Add Class

```
.popclose {
     text-align: right;
     position: absolute;
     top: 3px;  // Change the value as per requirement;
     right: -4px; // Change the value as per requirement;
     z-index:1000;
     color: #029dff !important;
     padding: 0px !important;
     background-color: transparent !important; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely due to your `ng-click="closePopup()"` not compiling.

Have a look at [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19267979/ng-click-not-working-from-dynamically-generated-html) to get to a work around.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and here is how I solved it.

Using the TemplateUrl parameter, I passed in an HTML template that makes up the body of the popup. I included the  tag in here, then used top: 0; right: 0; (with minor tweaks) to get the icon in the top right corner of the popup. By passing it in through the TemplateUrl parameter the ng-click compiles correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Use "template" instead of "title".
And adjust the CSS of this property so that it is equal to the title.