# angular ng-click event not firing

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a function that adds certain html to my page when called :

```
function htmlAppend(i)
       {
        dynamicHtml = dynamicHtml + '<div id="list_item_wrapper">' + 
        '<div class="list_item_template" id="list_image_wrapper">' +
        '<img class="list_image_style" ' +
        'src=" ' + jsonData.cars[i].ImgURL  + ' "/>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="list_item_template white_font car_details_wrapper">' +
         jsonData.cars[i].CarName+ '<br>' +
         jsonData.cars[i].Brand  + '<br>' +
         jsonData.cars[i].Model  + '<br>' +
         jsonData.cars[i].FuelType + '<br>' + 
        '<span style="font-size:40px;">' +
        '&#8377; ' + jsonData.cars[i].Price + 
        '</span> <br> ' +
        jsonData.cars[i].Experience +
        '<input type="button" id="buy_now_btn" class="button1" ng-click="alert("hi")">Buy</button>' +
        '</div>' +
        '</div>'
       }
```

**Problem :** Now this html is displayed correctly in my page but for some reason when button is clicked `ng-click` event doesn't fire , when i replaced it with `onClick` then `onClick` fires . i am unable to understand why `ng-click` is not firing , can somebody help ?

**Additional Info** : `htmlAppend` is a `private` function of a service that is called from the controller upon some user input.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ng-click not working from dynamically generated HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19267979/ng-click-not-working-from-dynamically-generated-html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't just write `alert` on your ng-click. When you write `alert("hi")` on your ng-click directive, it automatically goes and look for a method in your controller that is named `$scope.alert()`. That is why `onClick` works, because it is just plain old JavaScript, where as `ng-click` involves scope binding.

In your controller, write this:

```
  $scope.alert=function(string){
    alert(string);
  };
```

and you are good to go. Here is the working [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/fXHzea0Ijf1QgcajfAQP?p=preview).

Edit: did not read carefully that you are dynamically binding it. Updated plnkr.

For this case you will need to compile it:

```
  var $el = $('<button ng-click=' + 'alert("hello")' + '>I am a button</button>');
  $compile($el)($scope).appendTo('#testing');
```

where `#testing` can be any DOM selector you want.

Still the point is to tell you you can't just write `alert` in `ng-click` directive.

Added bonus: do not write DOM manipulating logic inside the controller. You may want to use a directive instead.

Comment: not working ! i guess because your html is static where as my html is dynamic

Comment: doesn't work if i pass a object that is binded to the view as a argument to the alert function

Comment: cant i compile without using jquery ?

Comment: @varunsinghal65 by object means an angular object? yes of course you can. I updated my plnkr again. check it out