# ng-click is not firing

Tags: javascript, angularjs

adding the following 'hyperlink' to html like:

```
<a style="color:white" ng-click="ClickMe()"><i class="fa fa-trash-o" style="color:white"></i>Click</a>
```

and then use this code to trigger `click` event like

```
 $scope.ClickMe = function () { alert("clicked"); }
```

works fine, but this did not work when  'hyperlink' generated dynamically like

```
 $('<a style="color:white" ng-click="ClickMe()"><i class="fa fa-trash-o" style="color:white"></i>Click</a>').insertAfter("#dashboard_link");
```

Could anyone explain why did that happen?

Comment: you shouldn't use jQuery to modify the DOM with an angular component.  jQuery doesn't update angular, so angular doesn't know there is a new binding to monitor.

Comment: you need to compile your code before rendering... [Please refer this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19267979/ng-click-not-working-from-dynamically-generated-html)

Comment: Add script where u adding this html .Using jQuery is not recommended,Use directive and jQlite for it

Answer (score 0):

Angular processes the bindings on load.  Since the element is generated dynamically, you will have to bind it dynamically as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a controller: You're going to want to use the $compile service.

```
var el =  $('<a style="color:white" ng-click="ClickMe()"><i class="fa fa-trash-o" style="color:white"></i>Click</a>').insertAfter("#dashboard_link");

$compile(el)($scope);
```

don't forget to inject $compile into your controller.

However as pointed out in the comments, there are better alternatives than using jquery to manipulate the dom.

Comment: that's assuming this is done in a controller;  based on the fact that they are using jQuery to modify the DOM, it's likely this is happening somewhere that angular has no control over.

Comment: no, it really isn't.  They may be trying to modify an element that is under angular's control, but there is no indication that this code is in a controller or not.  Besides the fact that if this were inside a controller, there are better ways to manipulate the DOM than to dropping to jQuery.

Comment: I don't think it's safe to assume anything from 1 line of Angular, 1 line of jQuery, and 1 line of HTML.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when you are using JQuery you haven't compiled it in a DOM.

You have to use *`$compile`* which Compiles an ***HTML string*** or ***DOM*** into a template and produces a template function, which can then be used to *link scope and the template together*.

Means *`$compile`* compiles the new ***DOM*** and link it to the current scope.

Please refer [to the AngularJs Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) for more detail.

Answer (score -1):

use javascript:void(0)  within your hyperlink

Comment: Can you clarify this answer? Seems to bring up more questions ;-)

Comment: that won't work;  angular will never fire the `ng-click` because it doesn't know it exists.