# AngularJS: ng-click not working in ui-grid cellTemplate

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Here I go again, with angular problems.

I have a grid in my HTML, which is just a line.

I'm copypasteing the controller.

```
app.controller('PanelController', function ($scope,  $compile, uiGridConstants){

    var actionTemplate = '<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents"><img class="addNotes" src="images/button/detail.gif" ng-click="dettaglio(row.entity)" /></div>';

    $scope.dettaglio = function(ritornoSearch, inspect) {
        console.log("make it function");
    };

    columnDefs: [
        { field: 'azioni', enableFiltering: false, width: 85, enableSorting: false, enableColumnMenu: false, cellTemplate: actionTemplate, displayName: 'Azioni'},
        { field: 'codeSubInstaller', headerCellClass: $scope.highlightFilteredHeader },
        { field: 'nomeSubInstaller', headerCellClass: $scope.highlightFilteredHeader },
        { field: 'cognSubInstaller', headerCellClass: $scope.highlightFilteredHeader },
        { field: 'codeFiscaleSubInstaller', headerCellClass: $scope.highlightFilteredHeader },
        { field: 'descStato' , headerCellClass: $scope.highlightFilteredHeader }
    ]
};
```

The question is: when I open it in my browser, the image doens't show up as clickable. If I try to click on it anyway, it doens't even provide me the console.log.

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you please show your html code ? how are you attching the actionTemplate to your html ?

Comment: Could you provide a plunkr? 
Also why do you have two arguments for dettaglio() function but then call it with one?

Comment: By the way your controller is missing ')' brace at the end

Comment: @RishabhJain You don't really have to attach that action, In my HTML there's `<section ng-controller="PanelController as panel">
 <div align="center"><br><br><br>
  <button id='toggleFiltering' ng-click="toggleFiltering()" class="btn btn-success">Nascondi Filtri</button><br><br> 
         <div class="myGrid"  ui-grid="gridOptions"></div>
 </div>        
</section>` , You don't have to attach it cause you call it in gridOptions.

Comment: @RishabhJain My controller is not missing, I just copypasted only what's required for this question.

Comment: @Olezt Probably that's really the problem. I'm going to check it now.

Comment: @Olezt Tried to write it properly with  `on-click="dettaglio(row.entity,true)"` still doesn't even write in my console.

Comment: @Kanza you are crating html dynamicaly, so angular does not know about the new compiled html, you need to write a directive that would compile dynamic html please refer to this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19267979/ng-click-not-working-from-dynamically-generated-html and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11771513/angularjs-jquery-how-to-get-dynamic-content-working-in-angularjs

Comment: @RishabhJain Ah, I see. Gonna read it all and try, then I'll give you feedback! Thank you!

Comment: @RishabhJain thats not correct. Please read the ui-grid docuemtation carefully. ui-grid provides an own compile logic so there is no need for an other compile.

Comment: @lin if the library provides its own compilation logic, then I completely agree that you don't need your own directive, I was just giving a generic answer to this type of issues .

Comment: @RishabhJain yea, by reading it the first time it seems like you are right. But by reading the question carefully it turns out that it is a problem depended on `ui-grid`. =)

Comment: @lin No, it doesn't.

Comment: @Kanza please check my answer. It should solve your problem `... the image doens't show up as clickable`, Please give some feedback. Thank you m8. Please check the plnkr i provided, it shows you how to solve the problem in the right way.

Answer (score 3):

Just do it like its documented in http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/305_appScope and compare this **[runnable plnkr demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/9O5zkIf3CNDQDI5wQl21?p=preview)** with your solution.

> $scope.grid.appScope is available in all templates that the grid uses. 
>   In a template, you access the scope using grid.appScope property

---

**In that way you need to change your template into the right syntax:
`ng-click="grid.appScope.dettaglio(row)"`:**

```
 var actionTemplate = '<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents"><img class="addNotes" src="images/button/detail.gif" ng-click="grid.appScope.dettaglio(row)" /></div>';
```

---

#### AngularJS application example with ui-grid:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngTouch', 'ui.grid']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$log', '$http', function ($scope, $log, $http) {

    $scope.dettaglio = function (row) {
        console.log(row);
        alert('inside');
    };

    $scope.gridOptions = {};

    $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs = [
        {name: 'name'},
        {name: 'gender'}, {
            name: 'ShowScope',
            cellTemplate: '<button class="btn primary" ng-click="grid.appScope.dettaglio(row)">Click Me</button>'
        }
    ];

    $http.get('https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-grid.info/gh-pages/data/100.json').success(function (data) {
        $scope.gridOptions.data = data;
    });

}]);
```

Comment: Well, sadly it doesn't work.

In my console it says "Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '(' is not a valid identifier at column 15 of the expression [grid.appScope.(row.entity)] starting at [(row.entity)]."

Comment: @Kanza please provide some feedback. Why doenst it work for you while its working fine in the plnkr demo? Have you checked the DEMO? http://plnkr.co/edit/9O5zkIf3CNDQDI5wQl21?p=preview Please compare it with your codes. I realy think the problem is related an your side now. The solution should work. Please add some more information so I can help you to fix this problem. We could also join a CHAT-Room if you like to?

Comment: Thank you very much, I found a solution and I posted it here so anyone can check it.