# ng-click property won't fire when placed on dynamically created button

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am dynamically building a table based on what SQL returns me.  In the example below, I can fill a table with the start time, end time and user with no issue:

```
var StartTime = document.createElement('td');
var EndTime = document.createElement('td');
var InUser = document.createElement('td');
StartTime.innerText = value[i].startTime;
EndTime.innerText = value[i].endTime;
InUser.innerText = value[i].inUser;
```

The output will be a table with the number of entries I have received from SQL.  What I would like to do now is create another td element to add to the last column of the table.  This will be a button that will allow me to show and hide certain rows.  For some reason, the ng-click functionality does not work when I click the button.  Below is how I create the td element and how I apply the button to it.

```
var ViewComments = document.createElement('td');
ViewComments.innerHTML = '<button type="button" ng-click="showHideComments()" class="r-primary-button">View Comments</button>';//apply click functionality.
```

When Ctrl + Shift + C clicking on the table to view the elements on the page, I can see that the row has the exact values that I specified (i.e. the type, ng-click and class).  The class property is working because I have the background of the button set to blue when highlighted which gives the "clicking effect."  I am not sure why the ng-click functionality is not working because I have used ng-click before in the application where buttons are not dynamically created.  I'm assuming this the issue?  If so, is there a way to get the ng-click functionality to work on dynamically create buttons?

I see in this stackoverflow that they are using $compile: 
[ng-click not working from dynamically generated HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19267979/ng-click-not-working-from-dynamically-generated-html)
Is this the only way to solve this problem?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Yes, you must use $compile.

Comment: Where to start with this one... why aren't you using `ng-repeat` to create your table? You don't need `$compile` if you do it "the Angular way". Read this before doing anything else: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14994391/64279

Comment: I've seen ng-repeat before, but how do take advantage of that once SQL returns its values?  The SQL table only gets returned when the user clicks on the "view comments" button.  Do I set the data that gets returned like so?  $scope.returnValues = commentsReturned?  And then  ng-repeat in the DOM will run and fill the table?  I've only been using JavaScript for a few weeks so I'm still fairly new to this.  Thanks again.

Comment: @SQLandJavaLearner, yes, you've got it. Or if you are using paging, you'd concatenate the new records returned by the server to your existing results array. If you're building a table, you'll probably also want to learn about `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end` - depending on the complexity of the table you are making.

Comment: @SQLandJavaLearner yes something like that, see my answer below

Comment: @SQLandJavaLearner, Don't listen to the people telling you to use `$compile`. That's for more complex scenarios. You don't need it for what you're trying to do. Go with @BunyaminCoskuner's answer.

Comment: Thank you all, that worked! However, I am running into an issue with ng-repeat-start and ng-repeat-end. I have asked the question here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44788149/create-new-rows-for-nested-objects in case anyone would like to lend a hand!

Comment: @SQLandJavaLearner, remember to click the check mark next to the answer that best answered your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why aren't you using angular utilities? This seems like a lot of work while it can be easily done with angular.

```
<table ng-if="values">
    <tr ng-repeat="value in values">
        <td>{{value.startTime}}</td>
        <td>{{value.endTime}}</td>
        <td>{{value.inUser}}</td>
        <td><button type="button" ng-click="showHideComments()" class="r-primary-button">View Comments</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Inside your controller

```
$http.get(someUrl).then(function(data){
    $scope.values = data;
});


$scope.showHideComments = function() {
    // do your thing here
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes go with [**compile**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile).

As the doc says that

> Compiles an HTML string or DOM into a template and produces a template function, which can then be used to link scope and the template together.

You can create a reusable directive which will take the dynamic string and compiles that.

An example

```
<div ng-controller="Controller">
  <element-create message='htmlString'></element-create>
</div>
```

Directive

```
angular.module("CompileDirective", [])
  .directive('elementCreate', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
      return { 
        restrict: 'E', 
        scope: {
            message: "="
        },
        replace: true,
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var template = $compile(scope.message)(scope);
            element.replaceWith(template);               
        },
        controller: ['$scope', function($scope) {
           ...
        }]
      }
  }])
```