# Click to delete dynamically created element in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Currently whatever the user enters in the text box and clicks the button, is being displayed inside anchor tags dynamically (all in new lines).

Textbox and the button (HTML file)-

```
<input type="text" name="inputText"><br>

<tr>
        <input type="button" value="ADD" ng-click="$ctrl.addtext()">
</tr>

<div id="outputDiv"></div>
```

JS function-

```
ctrl.addtext = function () {
    var div = document.getElementById('outputDiv');
    div.innerHTML += "<a href='' style='margin-left:10px'>"+newtext+"</a><br>";
}
```

Is there a way to add a close/remove button (like an X) at end of the dynamically created anchor tags, that On-click remove those particular rows of only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Edit 3

Using a different component syntax:

```js
function scanExceptionComponentCtrl ($scope, $compile) {
  
  var ctrl = this;
  ctrl.addtext = function (e) {
    var newtext = document.listForm.inputText.value
    var outputDiv = $('#outputDiv');
    var newRow = $compile("<a href='' style='margin-left:10px'>"+newtext+" - <span ng-click='$ctrl.removeRow($event)'>X</span></a><br>")($scope);
    newRow.appendTo(outputDiv)
  };

  ctrl.removeRow = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.target.parentNode.remove();
  };
  
};

// angular.module('consoleApp', [])
 angular.module('consoleApp',[])
   .component('scanException', {
  templateUrl: 'templateId',
  controller: scanExceptionComponentCtrl
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="consoleApp">
  <scan-exception></scan-exception>  
  
  
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="templateId">
 <form name="listForm">
  <table border="0" cellspacing="0">
   <tr>
    <input type="radio" style="margin-left:10px;" name="checkRadio" value="append" checked><span class="add-file-text" style="font-weight:bold;">Add File to Exception List</span><br>
    <input type="text" style="width:250px;height:30px;margin-left:10px;margin-top:10px;" name="inputText"><br>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <input type="button" style="margin-left:10px;margin-top:10px;" value="ADD" ng-click="$ctrl.addtext($event)">
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>
     <div id="outputDiv"></div>
    </td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </form>
</script>
  
</div>
```

#### Edit 2 - updates to use jQuery syntax and pass $scope into $compile

add an ng-click and use $compile (make sure to include in controller)

```
ctrl.addtext = function () {
  var outputDiv = $('#outputDiv');
  var newRow = $compile("<a href='' style='margin-left:10px'>" + 'newtext ' + " <span ng-click='removeRow($event)'>X</span></a><br>")($scope);
  newRow.appendTo(outputDiv)
};
```

create function

I'm not sure exactly what element you wanted to remove.

```
ctrl.removeRow = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.target.parentNode.remove();
};
```

#### Code Snippet

There may be differences in how you are writing your components/controllers.

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('myController', function ($scope, $compile) {

    $scope.addText = function () {
     var outputDiv = $('#outputDiv');
     var newRow = $compile("<a href='' style='margin-left:10px'>" + 'newtext ' + " <span ng-click='removeRow($event)'>X</span></a><br>")($scope);
     newRow.appendTo(outputDiv)
   };
   
   $scope.removeRow = function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     e.target.parentNode.remove();
   };


  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
 
  
  <button ng-click="addText($event)">add text</button>
  
  
  <div id="outputDiv"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: ng-click="$ctrl.removeRow($event)" gives me an error because of the double quotes I suppose.
Replaced that with single quotes and added a console.log message inside the function, but did not get that displayed on clicking the X.

Comment: Did you function include `preventDefault`?

Comment: yes it does.. my editor shows that there is a syntactic error as i include $ctrl.removeRow($event) inside the double quotes

Comment: Maybe this will help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19267979/ng-click-not-working-from-dynamically-generated-html

Comment: I think the issue is related to compiling.

Comment: Ok I interchanged the double and single quotes and the syntax error is no more there.. but still when i click on the X it doesn't display the console.log message that I added to debug.
Can you please add a fiddle if you don't mind

Comment: Not too keep you waiting, but I won't be able to until tomorrow.

Comment: no problem.. I think the problem is I'm unable to reach/call the function removeRow on clicking the X

Comment: Check my edit.  Any reason why you are not using jQuery syntax?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166370/discussion-between-manishk-and-mtmoran).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `$event` property in angular or something like a html-5 data attribute to retrieve the info of the clicked element. Roughly your code would look like this:

HTML:

```
<input type="button" value="ADD" ng-click="$ctrl.addtext($event)">
```

and JS

```
ctrl.addtext = function (event) {
    var clickedElem = document.getElementById(event.target.id);
    // do whatever you want with the element.
    var div = document.getElementById('outputDiv');
    div.innerHTML += "<a href='' style='margin-left:10px'>"+newtext+"</a><br>";
}
```